# For newly installed modules, how do I get `ipython` import autocomplete to work?

Tags: python, autocomplete, module, ipython

I have just installed the `sqlalchemy` module in my computer but when I type `import sql` and <kbd>TAB</kbd> in the ipython prompt the autocomplete only suggests me the builtin `sqlite3` module.

How do I get ipython to also suggest `sqlalchemy` on the import autocomplete?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on this message,

```
In [1]: import sq[TAB]
Caching the list of root modules, please wait!
(This will only be done once - type '%rehashx' to reset cache!)
```

have you tried `%rehashx` ?

Comment: Quiting ipython is not enough (I did it tons of times already), but `%rehashx` worked!

Comment: Anybody know how to trigger this during the install process? I see the function here, but don't know how to access it: 

ipython.git $ git grep rehashx
IPython/config/profile/pysh/ipython_config.py:%rehashx
IPython/core/completerlib.py:            print("(This will only be done once - type '%rehashx' to "
IPython/core/magics/osm.py:        and %rehashx functions, which automatically create aliases for the
IPython/core/magics/osm.py:    def rehashx(self, parameter_s=''):