# installed cvxpy, i can import but doesn't autocomplete in ipython

Tags: python, autocomplete, ipython, cvxpy

so I installed cvxpy following the instructions https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvxpy and it works but it doesn't autocomplete in ipython ie.

```
import cvxpy as cvx
```

works just fine but

```
import cv<TAB>
```

only gives me the `cvxopt` completion...

Any ideas how to fix this?

thank you

PS. I 'm running ubuntu if this matters at all

EDIT:

I should've said I had already tried `%rehashx` and it didn't change anything...

This was suggested in this question [How do I add a module to the ipython autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151003/how-do-i-add-a-module-to-the-ipython-autocomplete)

Also, in eclipse I managed to get tab completion to work by going to

Window > preferences > PyDev > Interpreter - Python > New Egg/Zip(s)

and navigating to the file /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cvxpy-0.1-py2.7.egg

So for those reasons I think it's not a duplicate, I would appreciate any feedback.

Thank you!

Comment: Does it work if you mv .../cvxopt .../hide-cvxopt ? What IPython version ? Is .../cvxpy-0.1-py2.7.egg zipped, unzip -l ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the app with flask; here is the code:

```
import readline
readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")

def complete(text,state):
    volcab = ['dog','cat','rabbit','bird','slug','snail']
    results = [x for x in volcab if x.startswith(text)] + [None]
    return results[state]

readline.set_completer(complete)

line = input('prompt> ')
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.