# How to view a Python class docstrings using jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, docstring

In the `spyder` IDE it is possible to press `ctrl+i` when instantiating a class to bring up the docstrings associated with that class. Is there a similar feature in `jupyter notebook`?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

For the current version of Jupyter notebook, you can hit `Shift-Tab` to bring up the signature and docstring of the class. This question is highly related to these other questions (so I'll flag this as a duplicate).

- [IPython Notebook Tab-Complete -- Show Docstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23687011/ipython-notebook-tab-complete-show-docstring)
- [How can I see function arguments in IPython Notebook Server 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30855169/how-can-i-see-function-arguments-in-ipython-notebook-server-3)

Comment: help(function_name)
is an alternative