# IPython and Jupyter autocomplete not working

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I am very new to this and don't know why the autocomplete is not working. I tried modifying the iPython config file, installed readline, but still nothing.

Comment: What have you tried, what do you see? Completions should show up when you type some code and press tab.

Answer (score 265):

A possible reason a user may believe that autocomplete is not working may be that **autocomplete is just taking too long**. Circa 2020-11-27 this is particularly true for Pandas when operating with *jedi* in a *Jupyter notebook* environment.

The issue can be solved by using the following [magic](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html) which deactivates *jedi*

`%config Completer.use_jedi = False`

For a deeper discussion follow the this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44186370/kernel-taking-too-long-to-autocomplete-tab-in-jupyter-notebook) and the links therein.

Comment: To make the change permanent locate your profile directory `ipython locate` and edit the relevant entry for `Completer.use_jedi` in the `ipython_config.py`.

Comment: It works for me. By the way, if it is the first time to edit the config file, you need first create it using: `ipython profile create`, see https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/intro.html for detail.

Answer (score 36):

the current Ipython with the Jupyter notebook doesn't require jedi.. So you have to just uninstall it with the following command.

```
pip uninstall jedi --yes
```

Comment: Interesting, but uninstalling jedi didn't remove the problem, the %config command is still needed.

Comment: Worked for me in a SageMaker Studio Notebook

Comment: uninstalling jedi worked for me. (%config worked too).

Comment: This did absolutely nothing to solve the problem for me on Mac, JupyterLab.  

I'd say basically every answer to this question that doesn't involve the config change is useless and incidental.

Comment: Didn't work for me. By uninstalling jedi in particular environment I got `AttributeError: module 'jedi' has no attribute 'settings'` error in kernel. Updating `ipython_config.py` worked and `%config Completer.use_jedi = False` also worked

Answer (score 16):

Seems like installing a specific version of `jedi` worked for me:

```
!pip install --upgrade jedi==0.17.2
```

Comment: This did the trick for me, i had jedi v. 0.17.0 and upgrading it re-enabled autocomplete.

Comment: For me too (Ipython 7.22, had jedi 0.17.0)

Comment: This didn't work at all for me when trying today for JupyterLab.  I'm not sure why this has been allowed to go on for so long.  I'm trying to teach Jupyter to several colleagues, and autocomplete being broken is a big UX fail.

Comment: For anyone arriving here with an "older" version of ipython, there was a bug with the Jedi dependency, (0.18.0 doesn't work, 0.17.2 does). https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/12740

Answer (score 5):

Installing:

```
C:> pip install pyreadline
```

works fine, as it was suggested in an older [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603798/ipython-tab-completion-not-working)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using jedi=0.18 with ipython=7.19 try this in your environment:

`pip install -U ipython==7.20`

see [this github discussion](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/12740).

Answer (score 3):

install jupyter contrib nbextensions by running

`pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions`

Next install js and css file for jupyter by running

`jupyter contrib nbextension install --user`

and at the end run,

`jupyter nbextension enable hinterland/hinterland`

The output of last command will be

```
Enabling notebook extension hinterland/hinterland...
      - Validating: OK
```

I refer from this:
[How to get autocomplete in jupyter notebook without using tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45390326/how-to-get-autocomplete-in-jupyter-notebook-without-using-tab/63761440#63761440)

Answer (score 2):

Ipython 6+ now has [jedi integration](http://blog.jupyter.org/2017/04/19/release-of-ipython-6-0/) built in.

update Ipython, and install jedi:

```
pip install ipython --upgrade
pip install jedi
```

If you are using Anaconda / conda:

```
$> conda update jupyter --update-dependencies
$> conda install jedi
```

Comment: the proper conda command is:
`conda update jupyter --update-deps`

Answer (score 1):

just below the Python logo there is a button saying

> not trusted

click on it and set it as trusted notebook.

Answer (score 1):

I use JupyterLab 3.0.6. I have ipython 7.19.0 and jedi 0.18 installed. As @DaveHalter indicated, better than <% config Completer.use_jedi = False> is to use the previous version of the jedi <pip install jedi == 0.17.2>.
In 2021-01-31 it worked perfectly for me.

Comment: I have installed JupyterLab 3.0.6. and just change/installed jedi version. Now, it's a working for me ! Thanks.

``pip3 install jedi == 0.17.2 ``

Answer (score 0):

If you tried to install tabnine with the juptyerlab extension manager, type in

```
pip uninstall jupyterlab_tabnine
```

in a shell. When you still get the problem, delete the folder

```
%appdata%\Python\share\jupyter\labextensions\@tabnine\
```

this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me

!pip install jedi --upgrade

first write  => **!pip install jedi --upgrade**
then for test, you can write **import pandas as pd**
after write pd. and then hit **tab**