# Kernel taking too long to autocomplete (tab) in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I just installed a few libraries for deep learning like `keras`, `theano` etc. The installation went fine but when I write code in Jupyter Notebook and press <kbd>tab</kbd> for autocompletion, the kernel of Jupyter Notebook seems to take too long for autocompletion. There have been times when it has taken minutes to display autocompleted options. I initially thought that the kernel hung so I had to restart it every time.

I read in another Stack Overflow post that installing `pyreadline` may help. I installed it but I'm still having the same problem.

Has anyone else faced this problem? How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 77):

You might try this at the top of your notebook:

```
%config Completer.use_jedi = False
```

Comment: The solution looks very strange, but it really solved the problem and stopped consuming a lot of my RAM and killing the kernel!

Comment: To get a bit more context on this solution, refer to https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10493 and https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/issues/931 where this solution is discussed.

Comment: Is there a way to put this in some config file so that I don't have to add this to every single notebook I create?

Comment: @Kayvee You can add `c.Completer.use_jedi = True` to an `ipython_config.py` file. https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/development/config.html

Comment: it doesn't work for me - Name of pandas dataframes take lot of time for auto complete.. dont know the reason. Any ideas how to debug?

Answer (score 0):

Jedi is the culprit.
Either you can disable it as suggested by @Miles above, 
or remove it completely.

```
pip uninstall jedi
```

Uninstallig worked for me. Jupyter suggestions are much faster now!

Comment: Don't do this. It messed up my Jupyter notebook kernels. Use either inline `%config Completer.use_jedi = False` or set `c.Completer.use_jedi = True` in `ipython_config.py`

Comment: I did not face any issue. how did it mess up?

Comment: It wouldn't load the kernel and show in terminal that it can't find jedi package.