# How to get autocomplete in jupyter notebook without using tab?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I would like to get an autocompletion feature in notebooks i.e. when I type something, a dropdown menu appears, with all the possible things I might type, without having to press the tab button. Is there such a thing?

I tried :

> %config IPCompleter.greedy=True

but this requires the tab button to be pressed

Answer (score 133, accepted):

There is an extension called [Hinterland](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/hinterland/README.html) for jupyter, which automatically displays the drop down menu when typing. There are also some other useful extensions.

In order to install extensions, you can follow the guide on this [github repo](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions). To easily activate extensions, you may want to use the [extensions configurator](https://github.com/Jupyter-contrib/jupyter_nbextensions_configurator).

Comment: If i am using a remote machine running jupyter notebook and I use it from my local machine via browser, where should I install the extensions?

Comment: @thebeancounter I have the extension installed only locally, that is on the machine where I access the notebook via browser. I don't have any extensions installed on my remote machine that runs jupyter notebook.

Comment: I've installed hinterland and it will only auto complete basic python stuff but will not autocomplete module functions (eg pd, np etc) how can I make it autocomplete those as well like pycharm?

Comment: @thebeancounter For me hinterland works with modules like numpy and pandas. Even if I do a relative import `import numpy as np` and type `np`, suggestions show up (e.g. np.abs). To troubleshoot this problem, more details on your setup are required. I'd suggest to open a separate question for your problem.

Comment: For those who are not familiar with Jupyter Notebook like me,
1) follow the official instruction to install these things: https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html
2) install browser configurator UI, following: https://github.com/Jupyter-contrib/jupyter_nbextensions_configurator
3) Open the jupyter notebook using command in terminal: `jupyter notebook`

Answer (score 67):

The auto-completion with Jupyter Notebook is so weak, even with hinterland extension. Thanks for the idea of deep-learning-based code auto-completion. I developed a Jupyter Notebook Extension based on TabNine which provides code auto-completion based on Deep Learning. Here's the Github link of my work: [jupyter-tabnine](https://github.com/wenmin-wu/jupyter-tabnine).

It's available on [pypi index](https://pypi.org/project/jupyter-tabnine/) now.  Simply issue following commands, then enjoy it:)

```
pip3 install jupyter-tabnine
jupyter nbextension install --py jupyter_tabnine
jupyter nbextension enable --py jupyter_tabnine
jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyter_tabnine
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Works great! But it has killed my new line (Shift+Enter) doesn't work any more in Jupyter Notebook. Any workaround for that?

Comment: @Harvey Hi, I block the first `Enter` to avoiding misoperation. If the hint window is shown, the first `Enter` will trigger the closing of the window.  For now, if you want new line when the hint is shown, you can just issue `Enter` and then issue `Enter` (or `Shift` + `Enter` if you want to execute current cell and create a new one.) I'm not sure whether it's a good design. Do let me know your fellings and suggestions.

Comment: On my laptop keyboard ´fn´ + ´Enter´ works. I'm getting used on than. Expected behavior was Alt+Enter for new line in cell and Shift+Enter for execution. Anyway considering how useful this plugin is this is just minor thing. Thank you!

Comment: In case one may have the `Permission denied` error when trying to install for jupyter, just add `--user` with the jupyter install command.

Comment: Also a kind warning: TabNine can take up a greate amount of memory and CPU resources. In my case, I run jupyter notebook from WSL(Ubuntu 18.04), and TabNine takes up ~1.5GB memory. The memory used can drop to ~200MB if you end the task from task manager and TabNine will autoboot itself the next time you type in your jupyter notebook. More details at https://github.com/zxqfl/TabNine/issues/43.

Comment: I tried it, but the drop down doesn't show stuff as good as hinterland, so I went back.

Comment: this code also work in android when i use jupyter?

Answer (score 33):

I would suggest [hinterland](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/hinterland/README.html) extension.

In other answers I couldn't find the method for how to install it from pip, so this is how you install it.

First, install jupyter contrib nbextensions by running

`pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions`

Next install js and css file for jupyter by running

`jupyter contrib nbextension install --user`

and at the end run,

`jupyter nbextension enable hinterland/hinterland`

The output of last command will be

```
Enabling notebook extension hinterland/hinterland...
      - Validating: OK
```

Answer (score 19):

As mentioned by @physicsGuy above, You can use the hinterland extension. Simple steps to do it.

Installing nbextension using conda forge channel. Simply run the below command in conda terminal:

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_nbextensions_configurator
```

Next Step enabling the hinterland extension. Run the below command in conda terminal:

```
jupyter nbextension enable hinterland/hinterland
```

That's it, done.

Comment: `Enabling notebook extension hinterland/hinterland...
      - Validating: problems found:
        - require?  X hinterland/hinterland`
This is the error in doing this

Comment: run this two commands `jupyter contrib nbextension install --system` and 
`jupyter contrib nbextension install --user` and then this to see the list `jupyter nbextension list`

Answer (score 8):

I am using Jupiter Notebook 5.6.0. Here, to get autosuggestion I am just hitting Tab key after entering at least one character.

```
 **Example:** Enter character `p` and hit Tab.
```

To get the methods and properties inside the imported library use same Tab key with Alice

```
  import numpy as np

  np. --> Hit Tab key
```

Comment: he want a solution without using tab key

Answer (score 7):

Without doing this `%config IPCompleter.greedy=True` after you import a package like numpy or pandas in this way;
`import numpy as np`
`import pandas as pd`.

Then you type in `pd.` then tap the tab button it brings out all the possible methods to use very easy and straight forward.

Comment: he want a solution without using tab key

Answer (score 3):

If you are using jupyter lab, you can simply go to settings -> code completion -> Enable autocompletion. It will have the same effect as hinterland without installing any extension.

Comment: this is a great help, and should be correct answer

Comment: This is the best answer, works for me. But should be more specific it is under settings -> Settings Editor -> code completion -> Enable autocompletion

Answer (score 1):

Add the below to your keyboard user preferences on jupyter lab (Settings->Advanced system editor)

```
{
    "shortcuts":[
        {
            "command": "completer:invoke-file",
            "keys": [
                "Ctrl Space"
            ],
            "selector": ".jp-FileEditor .jp-mod-completer-enabled"
        },
        {
            "command": "completer:invoke-file",
            "keys": [
                "Ctrl Space"
            ],
            "selector": ".jp-FileEditor .jp-mod-completer-enabled"
        },
        {
            "command": "completer:invoke-notebook",
            "keys": [
                "Ctrl Space"
            ],
            "selector": ".jp-Notebook.jp-mod-editMode .jp-mod-completer-enabled"
        }

    ]
}
```

Comment: Note: this question is about jupyter notebook. For JupyterLab there is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58445239/6646912) created prior to your answer and you answer might fit there better. Although I must say this is not the answer I would expect, it is technically correct - no using tab here ;)