# Autocomplete jupyter notebook without write any time %config IPCompleter.greedy=True

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm want have autocomplete in jupyter notebook. I want the feacture give by the

> %config IPCompleter.greedy=True

command but I don't write/run any time this line. There is a method for include it in setting of jupyter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get autocomplete in jupyter notebook without using tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45390326/how-to-get-autocomplete-in-jupyter-notebook-without-using-tab)

Comment: The post that you have mentioned want the autocomplete feacture without press tab while I want autocomplete without the above command. It's Ok for me press tab for autocomplete