# JupyterLab autocomplete without tab

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

Pressing tab each time you want to automcomplete seems time-consuming. Ideally, you just type in the first couple of letters and you get a drop down list without pressing tab.

In Jupyter notebook, there were some extensions that you could install to get this functionality. https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions

Is it possible to get this on JupyterLab?

Thanks

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60250631/12268505) might be helpful, too.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The [jupyterlab-lsp](https://github.com/krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp) extension offers this as an opt-in feature. After installing the extension in JupyterLab 3.0+ (which is two part: `jupyterlab-lsp` and the language server of your choice - see the linked instructions) you need to enable it in `Advanced Settings Editor` → `Code Completion` → `continuousHinting`:

[image]

Disclaimer: I am one of the authors. This feature is still under development.

Comment: How do I get the `code completion` tab in my jupyter lab settings. Is there anything separate needs to be installed?

Comment: Did you install `jupyterlab-lsp` as in the answer? Is it green in `jupyter labextension list`. Also, you need to restart JupyterLab after installation. What is your JupyterLab version?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I installed `tabnine` and I think it messed up my extensions and disabled it, that's why I couldn't see `code completion`. But now everything works just fine. BTW thanks for creating this lifesaver extension for `jupyterlab` :)

Comment: @0x64 it is quite likely that something is wrong with your configuration or installation, because as you can see byt the number of upvotes it works for many other users.

Comment: Be advised that that things have (apparently) moved on since the original posting.  This extension now appears to require 4.0.6 <= JupyterLab version <5.0.0a0 according to the readme file on github.  So, guess I'm going to have to wait until I have more time to install it (since my Anaconda--installed two months ago--has version 3.6.3 of Jupyterlab). But looks cool!!

Answer (score 2):

In Jupyterlab 4.10 you can go to: settings - code completion - enable autocompletion.