# Is there an equivalent to hinterland notebook extensions in JupyterLab?

Tags: jupyter-lab

I've always enjoyed using the Hinterland Jupyter Notebook extensions for code completion because you don't have to tab to autocomplete. I'm trying to migrate to JupyterLab and I'm not keen on tab-completion. I've looked through https://github.com/search?q=topic%3Ajupyterlab-extension&type=Repositories and I haven't been able to find a Hinterland equivalent.

Is there any way of getting Hinterland or similar code-completion hints without using tab on JupyterLab?

Comment: Potential duplicate: [JupyterLab autocomplete without tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58445239/jupyterlab-autocomplete-without-tab)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative would be VS-Code's integrated Jupyter Notebook environment. VS Code is arguably much more powerful and customizable than Jupyter Notebook/Lab, autocompletion (without having to tab) is standard-issue, there's also a (supposedly) AI-powered completion engine. It would take some getting used to, but so far I'm a happy user.

Comment: Interesting, I've been playing around with it and it works really well. It has code completion for numpy, matplotlib etc. It works really well. It also has a show all active variables in jupyter so you can track all your live variables very easily. Very impressive. I'll keep playing around with it some more, the live variables and plot view is really neat.

Comment: Very glad to hear it works well for you. Regarding IntelliCode i.e. "AI-powered completion", I've just double-checked and it only works in code files for now. Likewise, some of the more useful extensions for VS Code also aren't usable in the Notebook environment.

Comment: Jupyterlab allows one to have an editor on a remote server without a GUI. The setup is more complicated with VSCode remote

Comment: As a person that has a browser open "for emergencies" during coding sessions -- having VS Code open (and especially, *Jupyter*) is painfully slow for both the coding part and browsing part. Another tab in the browser feels fine. Not a happy user ever since. But maybe I just need to have a beefier machine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out JupyterLab-Monaco extension?  It's is still in early "proof of concept" stage though.

https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-monaco

Comment: Monaco looks like it's still in an early stage of development. No worries though, I've gone back to jupyter notebook and uninstalled jupyter lab for now. Hinterland is an absolute must for me so I'll migrate once there's a working version of that available.