# How to get code previewed in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, github, jupyter-notebook, vscode-extensions

While working with Jupyter Notebook, I'd like the code I've previously entered to automatically appear as a suggestion (preview) when I start typing it again. For instance, if I've previously typed the code "nltk.corpus.state_union.fileids()", the next time I begin typing it, such as starting with "nlt," the remaining portion of the code should be displayed as a preview without being fully typed into the cell. How to achieve it?
I heard that connecting Jupyter Notebook with Visual Studio extension using a GitHub key might be the solution. If that's the case, could someone kindly guide me on how to set it up?

I've searched google and asked ChatGPT, but found nothing useful... Just as mentioned, I expect that the codes can be previewed in the cell when they are typed again.

Comment: Is [this](https://blog.jetbrains.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/image-3.gif) like what you are talking about? That uses tab autocomplete in JupyterLab. I think it works in current versions of Jupyter Notebook v7 (based on [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/6709) and [here](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/What%20is%20the%20Jupyter%20Notebook.html#Notebook-web-application), not the latter says "tab completion" so I don't know if it shows options/preview). (I need to check myself but it wasn't opening vis mybinder fast enough right now.)

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it's not quite like a pop-up box with predefined options. When you input certain letters, the remaining part of the code will automatically appear in the cell with a darker color. This darker color indicates that the displayed code is a guess (based on the code history) for the code you may want to continue typing.

Comment: Have you worked through what is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60161350/8508004), including links to other posts there? Keep in mind that Jupyter Notebook Version 7 is very new and so some of the stuff that was formerly supported there won't yet work until developers catch up. So you may want to try earlier versions of Jupyter Notebook or NbClassic. To get a better sense of what I am talking about see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76837597/8508004).

Comment: Wow, you are really helpful. I will try these sites. If the issue is solved, I'll be back. Thanks a bunch.