# JupyterLab autosuggestion without tab

Tags: jupyter-lab

Pressing tab each time you want to automcomplete seems time-consuming. Ideally, you just type in the first couple of letters and you get a drop down list without pressing tab.

Comment: And what is your question? If it is just a feature recommendation then you are at the wrong place. If it is included but you don't know how to do it, please edit your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JupyterLab autocomplete without tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58445239/jupyterlab-autocomplete-without-tab)