# Jupyter Notebook -autosuggestion

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Im currently learning the basics in Python and im running my codes on Jupiter notebook, however what i cannot figure out is - How to enable the auto-correction setting which provides you with the code beforehand/ thus brings you overview of the potential functions one can use. Im using a Macbook!
I would really appreciate it if somebody can help me.
Best wishes

Comment: Does these answer your question: [JupyterLab autocomplete without tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58445239/jupyterlab-autocomplete-without-tab), or [How to get autocomplete in jupyter notebook without using tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45390326/how-to-get-autocomplete-in-jupyter-notebook-without-using-tab)?