# Enable auto-complete without needing a key press in Python/Jupyter notebooks?

Tags: autocomplete, pycharm, jupyter-lab, typing

I need more efficient ways to type code. I'm physically disabled and can't use a physical keyboard. I'm writing this text with Dragon NaturallySpeaking, but that is pretty rubbish for writing code, so I have to resort to an on-screen keyboard.

I've learned about auto-completion in Jupyter by pressing TAB. Is there perhaps a way to enable it without a key? I would like as many auto-completion suggestions as possible.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! Questions that ask for general guidance regarding a problem approach are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a correct answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), and  [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") then edit your post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JupyterLab autocomplete without tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58445239/jupyterlab-autocomplete-without-tab)

Comment: Hi @DucciVinci while this is already answered in the linked suggestion (which means that this question will get closed), I would like to highlight the ongoing JupyterLab accessibility initiative; we will be meeting next week after [JupyterLab team meeting](https://github.com/jupyterlab/team-compass#weekly-developer-meeting) and I'm sure we would love to hear your feedback on priorities for making JupyterLab more accessible if you are interested in giving feedback.