# How do I enable autocompletion in jupyterlab?

Tags: jupyter-lab, python-3.11

I need to enable jupyterlab autocompletion. But when trying to install via command "pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions", it seems to be incompatible with Python 3.11.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JupyterLab autocomplete without tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58445239/jupyterlab-autocomplete-without-tab)