# Jupyter notebook autocompletion

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, intellisense

i cant use the autocompletion on jupyter, i already used `%config IPCompleter.greedy=True` and also installed **jedi** but nothing has changed im still facing the same problem.

i searched after using `%config IPCompleter.greedy=True` if the greedy parameter gets activated and it really does however its like if its not installed.[image]

[EDIT] : to explain more after pressing tab popup nothing appears

does any one have a solution for my probleme ?

thankyou .

Comment: do you mean after pressing tab popup doesn't appear or are you expecting the pop up automatically when you type?

Comment: if latter then look at his stackoverflow post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45390326/how-to-get-autocomplete-in-jupyter-notebook-without-using-tab/50105503

Comment: yes thats exactly what i mean

Comment: @abhilb i saw that post and read this comment : 

Without doing this %config IPCompleter.greedy=True after you import a package like numpy or pandas in this way; import numpy as np import pandas as pd.

Then you type in pd. then tap the tab button it brings out all the possible methods to use very easy and straight forward.
but its note the same case for me