# Can't open jupyter notebook as an administrator using Anaconda

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have Anaconda and I would like to use jupyter notebook. Basically when I do not open Anaconda as an administrator everything works well. When opening Anaconda as an administrator I get an error message when opening Anaconda in the browser that says (translated)

*"Access denied - The file /C:/Users/localadmin/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-9808-open.html is not readable."*

The strange thing is that for example, I do not have any problems opening Spyder from Anaconda as an administrator. Can you think about the reason I get this error and how I can solve it? I'd appreciate every comment.

**Reminder**: As I have not received an answer solving my issue yet, I would like to remind you on this question. Does anybody have an idea what the problem might be?^
Can you think about any reason why this happens?

Comment: How did you install notebook, via conda install or via pip?

Comment: Thanks for your comment kobooya. I am not sure how I installed it. But I did not use pip (as I do not know what this is). Either is was preinstalled or I just clicked on the Jupyter botton in the Anaconda window

Comment: Can you try opening anaconda prompt and typing "conda install notebook" (just try reinstalling it)

Comment: Thanks koobooya for your answer. When I do this I get the message "# All requested packages already installed."

Comment: Okay, that sould be okay. How do you start notebook? Via "jupyter notebook" command in Anaconda?

Comment: Thanks kabooya for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it. Bascially I start jupter via the icon in Anaconda. But I also tried - as suggested by Bhargav "JUPYTER NOTEBOOK --allow-root" in the terminal. Both open the browser BUT report the same error message.

Comment: The strange thing is that if I am not an Administrator I can start jupyter without problems AND if I am an Administrator I can for example start Spyder without problems. But the combination of being an Administrator and using Jupyter just does not work. Any idea what I can do?

Comment: @kabooya: Any comments on my last comment? I'd highly appreciate every further comment from you.

Comment: Do you really need to start Notebook in admin mode? You say it works when not running it as admin. Don't know what the problem would be...

Comment: Thank kabooya for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it. Basically I am currently (once again) experiencing a problem with Anaconda, especially with extensions of jupyter notebook (see discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66459029/cant-use-extension-in-jupyter-jupyter-contrib-nbextensions) and I just wanted to try the extensions in Admin mode and see if this might solve the problem (I doubt't it but I can't rule it out until having tried it).

Comment: Did you reinstall your environment? Did you reinstall it in admin mode?

Comment: I did not reinstall the environment because I have installed and reinstalled it 20 times until I could run the python packages (pyomo, keras) that I wanted. I have been experiencing many many problems with Anaconda (I reinstalled the whole anaconda also at least 10 times)

Comment: @kabooya: Any idea what the problem might be?