# Jupyter Lab or Jupyter Notebook autocompletion won't work

Tags: python-jedi

Last night I have updated all of `pip` packages and suddenly Jupyter autocompletion stop working. I have tried to use different release of `jedi` packages but won't help. I have used `nbextenstion` option as well with no luck.

I'm using `jedi` 0.18.0

`Python` version 3.91

Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1):

This is a compatibility issue between IPython and Jedi and will be fixed with the next IPython release: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/12740 (and my comment: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/12740#issuecomment-751273584)

The solution is to temporarily use `pip install jedi==0.17.2`.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling `jedi` and enabling `Hinterland` from `nbextension` will resolve the issue.

The other way is keeping `jedi` and writing  `%config Completer.use_jedi = False` on the top of `Jupyter notebook`

For more details follow this [magic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40536560/ipython-and-jupyter-autocomplete-not-working)