# API for pandas_datareader

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance, pandas-datareader

i'm trying to learn pandas_datareader and have been searching on google, so far i haven't found any details API
Only found this https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html#yahoo-finance-options

but it's lack of details such as following pic shows, data has many more functions or properties which I have no idea about. 
So does anyone know where I can find info about those details? I'm looking for something like java api giving details of each function/property

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature is there:

all you have to do is press shift + tab a few times.

[image]

If it doesn't work then install `pip install pyreadline`

Source: [IPython tab completion not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603798/ipython-tab-completion-not-working)

Another option is to use

```
?data.div
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, i'm still learning, much appreciated

Comment: @ikel no problem at all :)